# Running execvp from 2D array parameter

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, execvp, execv

I'm attempting to run execvp using the data from a char[][] type (aka an array of strings). Now I know that  `execvp()`  takes a pointer to a string as its first parameter and then a pointer to an array of strings as its second - in fact I have even used it successfully before as such - however I cannot seem to get the correct combination of pointers & strings to get it to work out below - whatever I try is deemed incompatible!

Any help very grateful :) -  I've removed my headers to compact down the code a bit!

```
struct userinput {
    char anyargs[30][30]; //The tokenised command
};

int main() {

    struct userinput input = { { { 0 } } }; //I believe is valid to set input to 0's
    struct userinput *inPtr = &input; //Pointer to input (direct access will be unavailable)

    strcpy(inPtr->anyargs[0], "ls"); //Hard code anyargs to arbitary values
    strcpy(inPtr->anyargs[1], "-lh");

    char (*arrPointer)[30]; //Pointer to an array of char *
    arrPointer = &(inPtr->anyargs[0]);

    printf("arrPointer[0]: %s, arrPointer[1]: %s\n", arrPointer[0],
            arrPointer[1]);

    printf("At exec case; ");
    execvp( arrPointer[0], arrPointer);
    perror("Command not recognised"); //Prints string then error message from errno

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `arrPointer = (inPtr->anyargs);` without & ?

Comment: Yes - correct me if I'm wrong - the -> operator de-references and returns the value - which we don't want as arrPointer and execvp dont take values directly - they take pointers to values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as `char[][]` in C. `execvp` requires an array of pointers to `const char`. This can be written as either `char * const *` or `char * const []`.

You however have an array of 30-characters-long arrays, not an array of pointers. The two types are not compatible, not interchangeable, and not convertible one to another in either direction.

In this line

```
char (*arrPointer)[30]; //Pointer to an array of char *
```

you attempt to declare a pointer to an array of char*, incorrectly. What you have declared instead is a pointer to `char[30]`, which is very different from what `execvp` expects.

The next line

```
arrPointer = &(inPtr->anyargs[0]);
```

purports to initialize a pointer to an array of `char*` with a pointer to `char[30]`, which cannot possibly be correct even if you declare a pointer to an array of `char*`, because the right hand side of the assignment is not a pointer to an array of `char*`, it's a pointer to `char[30]` and no sequence of casts, indices, addresses and dereferences will turn one to the other.

An array of 30 pointers to `char` is declared like this:

```
char* arguments[30];
```

A dynamically-sized array of pointers to `char` is made like this:

```
char** arguments = calloc (nargs, sizeof(char*));
```

You need to use one of those if you want to call `execvp`.

In either case each pointer in the array of pointers must be initialized to point to an individual NUL-terminated character array (possibly to elements of your `char[30][30]` array) and the last pointer (one after all the argumenrs we want to pass) must be set to  NULL. (I wonder how you expected to find a NULL in a `char[30][30]`).

Answer (score 2):

The [`execvp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) expects as second argument a `char *const argv[]`.  This means an array of pointers to char.  This is different from a `char[30][30]` which is represented in memory as 30x30 contiguous chars  (so no pointer).

To solve this, define your structure

```
struct userinput {
    char *anyargs[30]; //space for 30 char* pointers
};
```

You could as well define `anyargs` as `char**` and initalize if dynamically with `(char**)calloc(number_of_args+1,sizeof(char*))`

Later, assign directly the pointers:

```
inPtr->anyargs[0] = "ls"; //Hard code (or use strdup() )
inPtr->anyargs[1] = "-lh";
inPtr->anyargs[2] = NULL; // end of the argument list !!!
char **arrPointer; //Pointer to an array of char *
arrPointer = inPtr->anyargs;
```

Edit: Caution: "***The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer.***".